# Subquery to Pull Specific Records

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have 3 tables, a, b and c. A relates to b which relates to c. I need to pull all the records from c that relate to all the records from a.

If table a has 2 records and c has 3 records and the following is true:

- c1 relates to a1 and a2
- c2 relates to a1
- c3 relates to a1 and a2

The query would then return c1 and  c3.

I just cant get my mind around it for some reason.

```
SELECT c.value
FROM c
INNER JOIN b
   ON c.b_id = b.b_id
INNER JOIN a
   ON b.a_id = a.a_id
WHERE c.value IN (???)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please show a [mcve] with sample table data in tabular format, and expected output.  You will get better results that way.

Comment: I'd love to give a better example but again, I'm having trouble getting my head around the problem. I will do better in the future. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: How does B relate to A and C? Give us sample data and expected results.

Comment: If you cannot explain your problem with sample table data, how do you expect someone else to understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and example code have different relation directions which is confusing. Accepting your code as indicator for the correct relation direction and modifying it by counting a's will give you a possible but not extremely elegant solution:

```
SELECT value FROM (
    SELECT c.value, COUNT(DISTINCT a.a_id) a_qty FROM c
    INNER JOIN b ON c.b_id = b.b_id
    INNER JOIN a ON b.a_id = a.a_id
    GROUP BY c.value
) WHERE a_qty = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a)
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that the Oracle optimizer will do a good job at making this execute efficiently, especially if the match columns are indexed:

```
SELECT *
  FROM c
 WHERE EXISTS
           (SELECT NULL
              FROM a
                   INNER JOIN b
                       ON (a.abmatch = b.abmatch)
                      AND b.cbmatch = c.cbmatch);
```